# SQL Server 2008 Report Builder Forms Authentication

Tags: sql-server-2008, forms-authentication, reportbuilder

Has anyone ever successfully gotten forms authentication to work with report builder? I have a client who wants to use report builder outside my company's domain. Would forms authentication work for this?

Answer (score 2):

We have report builder working with the membership provider.  It is possible. I used this for the http://blogs.msdn.com/bimusings/archive/2005/12/05/500195.aspx and it works great.  Even got single sign on.

I can't get the prompt from showing, but entering forms credentials can work.. It depends on the authentication source; if using membership provider, you can use forms auth as long as the site can connect to the API/database.

You have to get the SSRS 2005 SDK and there is a forms authentication sample, which you can modify to use membership provider (if you are using it), and use that as the code-base.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

No, not for building reports as part of reporting services.  Forms authentication is not an option here as you can't change how reportbuilder authenticates.
Both reportbuilder 1.0 and 2.0 need to talk to the website that has all of web services machinary.  www.site.com/reportserver the user interface is www.site.com/report
Even if you open up your web site to not need authentication the report builder application won't work.
A user can build reports with report builder 2.0 independent of the site but they won't be able to publish from report builder.  The could publish thru the website itself.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=DBDDC9B6-6E19-4D4B-9309-13F62901B0D5&displaylang=en